# Error: Could not find client component Shopify hydrogen custom storefront

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-hydrogen

So I came up with this weird issue I've got no idea why it happened. This is e-com site I was using shopify hydrogen to build and deploy. I was ok under dev enviroment, but the following errors shows up when I tried to deploy. Then I found 'yarn preview' also gave the same error. Any help on this?

[image]

```
react-dom.production.min.js:189 Error: Could not find client component HomeProductBanner-NzY1NjE3NDQ3
    at Ep (react-server-dom-vite.js:49:1)
    at wp (react-server-dom-vite.js:83:1)
    at Qp (react-server-dom-vite.js:404:1)
    at Kp (react-server-dom-vite.js:462:1)
    at Gp (react-server-dom-vite.js:512:1)
    at r (react-server-dom-vite.js:565:1)
Vo @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
o.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:190
Hu @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
us @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
yc @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
Kd @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
qd @ react-dom.production.min.js:283
Et @ react-dom.production.min.js:281
gc @ react-dom.production.min.js:270
S @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
dn @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
react-dom.production.min.js:189 Error: Could not find client component HomeSocksBanner-MTYyNTk5NzAzMQ
    at Ep (react-server-dom-vite.js:49:1)
    at wp (react-server-dom-vite.js:83:1)
    at Qp (react-server-dom-vite.js:404:1)
    at Kp (react-server-dom-vite.js:462:1)
    at Gp (react-server-dom-vite.js:512:1)
    at r (react-server-dom-vite.js:565:1)
Vo @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
o.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:190
Hu @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
us @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
yc @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
Kd @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
qd @ react-dom.production.min.js:283
Et @ react-dom.production.min.js:281
gc @ react-dom.production.min.js:270
S @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
dn @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
react-dom.production.min.js:189 Error: Could not find client component HomeLottery-LTE1NzcyNjUxMjc
    at Ep (react-server-dom-vite.js:49:1)
    at wp (react-server-dom-vite.js:83:1)
    at Qp (react-server-dom-vite.js:404:1)
    at Kp (react-server-dom-vite.js:462:1)
    at Gp (react-server-dom-vite.js:512:1)
    at r (react-server-dom-vite.js:565:1)
Vo @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
o.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:190
Hu @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
us @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
yc @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
Kd @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
qd @ react-dom.production.min.js:283
Et @ react-dom.production.min.js:281
gc @ react-dom.production.min.js:270
S @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
dn @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
react-dom.production.min.js:189 Error: Could not find client component HomeHands-ODQwMjg5NDM4
    at Ep (react-server-dom-vite.js:49:1)
    at wp (react-server-dom-vite.js:83:1)
    at Qp (react-server-dom-vite.js:404:1)
    at Kp (react-server-dom-vite.js:462:1)
    at Gp (react-server-dom-vite.js:512:1)
    at r (react-server-dom-vite.js:565:1)
Vo @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
o.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:190
Hu @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
us @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
yc @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
Kd @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
qd @ react-dom.production.min.js:283
Et @ react-dom.production.min.js:281
gc @ react-dom.production.min.js:270
S @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
dn @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
localhost/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
localhost/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
```